# How to switch the time to different time when the current is equal to the start time

Tags: javascript

I need to switch this time start time 11:55 and end time 12:10 to start time 12:55 to end time 13:10 when the first start time 11:55 and end time 12:10 is call how do I do that in JavaScript, because I'm new to JavaScript
This is the code:

```
var myVar = setInterval(checktime ,5000);
function checktime()
{ 
var currentD = new Date();
//this si the start and end time i have set for starting
var startHappyHourD = new Date();
//startHappyHourD.setHours(11,55,00);
var endHappyHourD = new Date();
//endHappyHourD.setHours(12,10,00); 

// then it will check
if(currentD >= startHappyHourD && currentD < endHappyHourD)
{
   var temp = startHappyHourD.toLocaleTimeString();
    alert(temp);

}
if(currentD >= endHappyHourD)
{   
    var temp2 = endHappyHourD.toLocaleTimeString();
    alert(temp2);
    stopCheck();
    // after check, it suppose to check here and change the time i dont know why it wont work
    if(startHappyHourD.getHours().getMinutes().getSeconds() == "11:55:00")
    {
            startHappyHourD.setHours(12,55,00);
            endHappyHourD.setHours(13,10,00);

    }
```

Comment: There could be different ways depending on your current code, readers need to know your current code and give you an answer based on that. So, I would suggest editing that in.

Comment: i have already edit the post. Please forgive, because im first time upload on stackoverfklow.

Comment: i wonder why this code wont change the time. Any comment? please help and guide thanks.

Comment: If I understand what you want to, you want to set a specific time and depending on the world timezone you add or reduce the hours and minutes. I'm I correct?

Comment: @Guerrato Ya something like this, and when reach specific time it will change to another specific time example like 11:55am to 12:10pm then change to 12:55pm to 13:10pm something like this –

Comment: @SteveLeeminhui Your question is very unclear for me, however, based on your comments here it seems you want a time counter running while you have your specific time set. So, for any unclear reason, you wish that every single time the time counter reaches the time defined, add 1 hour to the start and end time. Am I correct?

A tip for you that is new in Stackoverflow always including your code and define your GOAL, PROBLEM and WISHES in the post.

Anyway, let me know if I understood your question correctly, please.

Comment: @Guerrato Nope. I didnt specify how the logic work so sorry for that, so now the logic is when reach 11:55am and it will popup a window and stay there until the time is over to the range of 12:10pm then it will auto close due to the time interval between these two times. My logic is like that. So sorry for the misunderstanding question.

Comment: @SteveLeeminhui No worries! :) I made the same thing when I started on Stack overflow a few time ago. So now I think I got it! Give me a time and I post an answer to your question. Just in case of confirmation:
You wish a solution that when the "clock" reach a time like 11:55 am you show a pop-up and keep it open until 12:10 pm, right?

Comment: @Guerrato YA. and can set an time interval to let the popup auto close. how do i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solve this question with my own. This is the function which will work.

```
var myVar = setInterval(checktime ,1000);
```

function checktime()
{

```
var popupWinWidth = 1200;
var popupWinHeight = 450;
var currentD = new Date();

var tempc1 = new Date();
tempc1.setHours(11,55,00);
var tempc2 = new Date();
tempc2.setHours(12,10,00);
var tempc3 = new Date();
tempc3.setHours(12,55,00);
var tempc4 = new Date();
tempc4.setHours(13,10,00);
```

Using if and else to compare time, example

```
if(currentD >= tempc1 && currentD < tempc2)
```

Inside if and else, first must set the time to string in order to can see AM and PM, then set to display 2 digit of hour and minute.

Set a variable to store the set interval time to calculate on and off. Then create a popup screen to display the time. this is the following code

```
var temp = currentD.toLocaleTimeString([], {hour: '2-digit', minute:'2-digit',hour12: false});
var x = tempc2 - tempc1;
var left = (screen.width - popupWinWidth) / 2; 
var top = (screen.height - popupWinHeight) / 4; 
var myWindow = window.open("", "myWindow", 'resizable=yes, width=' + popupWinWidth + ', height=' + popupWinHeight + ', top='+ top + ', left=' + left);
myWindow.document.body.innerHTML = '<center style="color:blue;font-size:350px;">'+ temp +'</center>';
myWindow.document.body.style.background = "#00FF00";
setTimeout(function(){myWindow.close()},x);
```

Then use an else if to compare another time.

Comment: Perfect! You got it by yourself it is awesome news! I'm so sorry I was too busy and I just returned here to answer you and found it. My apologies for taking too long.